# CE Cache Static not serving cached home page

Tags: htaccess, ce-cache, caching

I am using CE Cache Static driver. All is getting cached and served as expected except for the home page. It is getting cached, but not served. I believe it is due to the below line of the htaccess, as the _static_cache_handler.php script is NOT being triggered:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static_cache/ce_cache/90ba68/static%{REQUEST_URI}/index\.html -f
```

So, despite the fact that index.html exsists in the `ce_cache/90ba68/static` directory, the RewriteCond is not passing.

This is working for me on other servers, but not the one I'm on now.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I can access the cached file in the browser with no issue, so I don't think it is a permissions issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found the issue and solution. It seems *sometimes* mod_dir will be setup to do it's thing before mod_rewrite. This means that %{REQUEST_URI} for the homepage could end up being `index.php` instead of `/`.

To account for this, I updated the the htaccess rule:

```
#------------------- CE Cache Static Driver -------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !ACT|URL [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static_cache/ce_cache/90ba68/static%{REQUEST_URI}/index\.html -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?:index\.php)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static_cache/ce_cache/90ba68/static/index\.html -f 
RewriteRule (.*) /_static_cache_handler.php%{REQUEST_URI}/index\.html [L,QSA]
```